# Gstreamer memory leak when switching between states

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, gstreamer

I've been trying to make a program for running some cameras through gstreamer. The program starts by setting up the pipeline and then switches between PLAYING or PAUSED states depending on the user input.
I notices after running this program for a while, that the memory use for the program would slowly increase over time. After trying a lot of different things I was able to reproduce the problem with a very small example program:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gst_init(&argc, &argv);
    GError* err = NULL;

    std::string pipeline_str = "fakesrc ! fakesink sync = false ";

    GstElement* pipeline = gst_parse_launch(pipeline_str.c_str(), &err);
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_READY);
    gst_element_get_state(pipeline, NULL, NULL, 4000000000ll);

    for (;;)
    {
        gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PAUSED);
        GstStateChangeReturn result = gst_element_get_state(pipeline, NULL, NULL, 4000000000ll);
        if (result != GST_STATE_CHANGE_SUCCESS){
            std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
            break;
        }      
        usleep(100);

        gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
        result = gst_element_get_state(pipeline, NULL, NULL, 4000000000ll);
        if (result != GST_STATE_CHANGE_SUCCESS){
            std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        usleep(100);
    }

    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

    gst_object_unref(pipeline);

    return 0;
}
```

Running this I can see the memory usage increase quite fast using htop. So it seems to me the problem happens when switching between states? Has anyone had similar issues?

**Update**

The accepted answer below works. But it seems the issue all along was not emptying the bus. If I get the bus with `GstBus* bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(GST_PIPELINE(pipeline));` and then flush the bus every loop with `gst_bus_set_flushing(bus, TRUE);`, then I don't see a rise in memory use anymore.

Comment: Implement some stop condition, and run it with [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) to see if there is indeed a memory leak, or you just keep accumulating resources without losing their references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State changes are async. You are generating more state change requests than the pipeline can handle, so most likely your message queue gets build up by those requests.

Wait for the state changes to complete before trying to change it again. Check the bus for the state change emitted from the pipeline.

EDIT, Example:

```cpp
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gst_init(&argc, &argv);
    GError* err = NULL;

    std::string pipeline_str = "videotestsrc ! fakesink sync=false";

    GstElement* pipeline = gst_parse_launch(pipeline_str.c_str(), &err);

    GstBus* bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(GST_PIPELINE(pipeline));

    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_READY);

    for (;;)
    {
        GstMessage* msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus, -1, GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED);
        if (msg->src == GST_OBJECT(pipeline))
        {
            gst_message_unref(msg);
            break;
        }
        gst_message_unref(msg);
    }

    for (;;)
    {
        gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PAUSED);

        for (;;)
        {
            GstMessage* msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus, -1, GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED);
            if (msg->src == GST_OBJECT(pipeline))
            {
                gst_message_unref(msg);
                break;
            }
            gst_message_unref(msg);
        }

        gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

        for (;;)
        {
            GstMessage* msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus, -1, GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED);
            if (msg->src == GST_OBJECT(pipeline))
            {
                gst_message_unref(msg);
                break;
            }
            gst_message_unref(msg);
        }
    }

    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

    gst_object_unref(bus);
    gst_object_unref(pipeline);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I added gst_element_get_state() and a success check to the code block in the description. As I understand gst_element_get_state() blocks until it receives a success or failure. With this added I'm still seeing the same quick increase in memory use.

Comment: `gst_element_get_state()` will return ` GST_STATE_CHANGE_ASYNC` in case of an async state change. I tried with a simple message loop from the bus - while racy it eliminated the memory increase.

Comment: Would you be able to share your message loop code? It would help a lot with the understanding. When I run the code in the description `gst_element_get_state()` returns GST_STATE_CHANGE_SUCCESS every time

Comment: Yeah I got that wrong, the return value is different, but it is not that easy unfortunately. I updated the post with an example. However the normal way is to have a proper run loop and a bus callback function. Also one should parse that message what state chnage has been reported. It should suffice for the example though I hope.

Comment: In fact, not sure if your approach works too. Perhaps the main reason is that you have no code running through the bus' message queue letting it grow indefinately.

Comment: I think you're right. I tried your code and it works well of course. I then tried my old code but added `gst_bus_set_flushing(bus, true)` in between state changes and that also eliminated the memory increase. Thank you very much for the help.